# Error: Semantic issue Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'

Tags: c, semantics

While creating a program with function prototype, a problem has occurred. It said:

```
Semantic issue Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'.
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void powr(int);

int main(void) {

    int n=1, sq, cu, quart, quint;

    printf("Integer  Square  Cube  Quartic  Quintic\n");

    do {

        sq = powr(n); //here is the error line
        cu = powr(n); //here is the error line
        quart = powr(n); //here is the error line
        quint = powr(n); //here is the error line
        printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d\n", n, sq, cu, quart, quint);
        n++;
    }
    while (n<=25);

    return 0;
}

void powr(int n)
{
    int a, cu, quart, quint;

    a=pow(n,2);
    cu=pow(n,3);
    quart=pow(n,4);
    quint=pow(n,2);
}
```

Comment: `powr` is defined as a void, prototype should be `int powr(int n)` if you want to use it this way

Comment: @amdixon and next issue with 4 return cases. :)

Comment: no idea what the user is doing here. really should be using the std math function pow like sq = pow(n, 2);... quint = pow(n, 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void powr(int n)
```

means that the function will return *nothing,* so you're not allowed to do something like:

```
sq = powr(n);
```

If you want your function to take an `int` and *return* an `int`, it should be:

```
int powr(int n)
```

(for both the prototype and the function definition).

---

In any case, variables that you set *within* the `powr` function are not available to the caller (and using globals is a very bad idea in general), so you'd need to either change the function to return just the square of the number and call it thus:

```
sq = powr (n);
cu = n * sq;
quart = powr (sq);
quint = n * quart;
```

Or you could pass the addresses of the variables into the function so they could be changed, something like:

```
void powr(int n, int *pSq, int *pCu, int *pTo4, int *pTo5) {
    *pSq = pow (n, 2);
    *pCu = *pSq * n;
    *pTo4 = pow (*pSq, 2);
    *pTo5 = *pCu * *pSq;
}
```

and call it with:

```
powr (n, &sq, &cu, &quart, &quint);
```

I would suggest using the former approach, given the level you appear to be learning at (no offence intended, just stating that to assist you in selecting the appropriate method).

Comment: @БолатТлеубаев If this answer proved helpful to you and it was able to answer your question, kindly accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer.